# How to find minimum and maximum of elements in a collection by different parameters?

Tags: java

I have a collection of the following:

```
Name            Age           Salary
John            30            $1000
Mary            25            $2000
Eric            22            $5000
```

How can I find the minimum age, salary and maximum age, salary?

Comment: Show the code that youve done.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Do you have some code you've tried that hasn't worked? Which version of Java?

Comment: Can you elaborate. Perhaps show some _code_. What `Collection`? Of what types? Show the code for the types.

Comment: At this point I'm unable to share the code. 
I have already overridden to compareTo method for sorting the list by names. Each person's data is an object in the PersonInfo collection.

Comment: Implement a comparator interface, and sort it according to age/salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of custom Objects (let's say Person objects), you can simply use the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) API with different [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Let's say your Person class has at least these three methods:

```
getName()
getAge()
getSalary()
```

Now you can implement an age comparator:

```
public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        if(p1.getAge() < p2.getAge()) return -1;
        else if(p1.getAge() > p2.getAge()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return this.compare(p1, p2) == 0;
    }
}
```

To get the max or min aged person, use Collections:

```
Collections.min(myList, new AgeComparator());
Collections.max(myList, new AgeComparator());
```

You can use another comparator (say SalaryComparator) that works like AgeComparator but considers salary.

```
Collections.min(myList, new SalaryComparator());
```

Naturally, you might use a single class for this as well and set a variable instead of using two different comparators.

Comment: Anything wrong with [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int))?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no information in your post I am going to make some assumptions.

You have an `Employee` class that looks like:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private BigDecimal salary;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

And you have some `Collection<Employee>` such a `List`:

```
final List<Employee> employees = ...
```

Now, I will also assume you have Java 8. To find the oldest `Employee` you would do:

```
Optional<Employee> oldest = employees.stream().
        max(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge));
```

You will see that this returns an `Optional` - this is because the behaviour when `employees` is empty is *undefined*. You will need to define your own behaviour.

Similarly for the other properties:

```
Optional<Employee> youngest = employees.stream().
        min(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge));

Optional<Employee> highestEarner = employees.stream().
        max(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));

Optional<Employee> lowestEarner = employees.stream().
        min(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));
```

Comment: I got this as the result -> Optional[Student@8efb846]
Please bare with me I'm very new to Java and programming.

Comment: @jdphenix I think the OP called `toString` on the `Optional<Student>`.

Comment: @user3837378 you need to call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) on the `Optional<Student>` to get the result. As I said, calling `get` may result in an `NoSuchElementException` if the `Collection` you passed in was empty - you might want to check for this with [`isPresent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) beforehand.

Comment: I used get and the result I got is - Student@8efb846

Comment: @user3837378 that certainly sounds like a result - what more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Comparator for each field

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class NameAgeSalary {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Float salary;

    private NameAgeSalary(String name, Integer age, Float salary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NameAgeSalary [name=" + this.name + ", age=" + this.age
                + ", salary=" + this.salary + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NameAgeSalary n1 = new NameAgeSalary("John",30,1000f);
        NameAgeSalary n2 = new NameAgeSalary("Mary",25,2000f);
        NameAgeSalary n3 = new NameAgeSalary("Eric",22,5000f);

        List<NameAgeSalary> list = Arrays.asList(n1,n2,n3);

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<NameAgeSalary>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(NameAgeSalary o1, NameAgeSalary o2) {
                /*
                 * uncomment the field you want to compare
                 */
                return o1.age.compareTo(o2.age);
//              return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
//              return o1.salary.compareTo(o2.salary);
            }

        });

        System.out.println("MIN "+list.get(0)); //min
        System.out.println("MAX "+list.get(list.size()-1)); //max
    }
}
```

Comment: How can un-comment in run time?

Comment: you can't. But you can write 3 Comparator's and choose the right one with some code